# C# string handling how get path and args from a string

Tags: c#, string, path, args

I have a string with quotes around the path as follows:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" arg1 arg2

If I use `Text.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, 2);` then I get the first space.

How to get the path and args ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting on the double quotes (Text.Split(new Char[] { '/"' }, 3);) then taking the last string in that array and splitting again on the space.

```
string[] pathAndArgs = Text.Split(new Char[] { '/"' }, 3);
string[] args = pathAndArgs[2].Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, 2);
```

I may have a syntax error in there, but you get what I mean.

Comment: Cheers

I went with this 

string[] fileAndArgs = this.AppPath.Text.Split(new Char[] { '"' }, 3);

Comment: This wouldn't work if the arguments are themselves double quoted to enable them to include spaces. (Not sure if that is the case here: original question does not clarify.)

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression like: `("".*?"")|(\S+)`

So your code would be something like:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"("".*?"")|(\S+)"); 
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(input);
for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(mc[i].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do text.split and work your way back from the end of the array.

```
var input = "C:\\blah\\win.exe args1 args2";
var array = input.split(' ');
var arg1 = array[array.length -2];
var arg2 = array[array.length -1];
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the arguments are themselves double quoted to enable them to include spaces. (Not sure if that is the case here: original question does not clarify.)